# Como hacer un contador de visitas en Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Estoy trabajando en Laravel 5.3 y estoy buscando algun paquete o algun dato como para hacer un contador de visitas tanto para una web en general, como para cada articulo que contiene el sitio. Me interesa mas el de cada articulo.

Comment: en esta web encontraras los codigos sobre el tema
url: [LINK](https://webfacilprogramacion.com/post/como-hacer-un-sistema-de-contador-de-visitantes-con-laravel-en-mi-sitio-web)

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

agregas `use Cache;`

Luego tendrás que agregar en tu método lo siguiente.

```
public function show($id){

    $variable = nameModelo::find($id);
    if(Cache::has($id)==false){
        Cache::add($id,'contador',0.30);
        $variable->total_visitas++;
        $variable->save();
    }
    return view('index')->with('variable',$variable);
}
```

Luego te vas a tu vista **index** o a donde hayas puesto en el view y quedaría tipo

```
<div aling="center">
    {{$variable->total_visitas}}
</div>
```

Así lo implemento yo en **Laravel 5.1**

Comment: Disculpa... se que ya es un tema muy viejo... Pero podrias explicarme tu codigo? nameModelo que id esta recibiendo? esto se guarda en alguna tabla?